# Function in Octave does not run

Tags: matlab, function, octave

I made the following function in octave for the Householder algorithm:

```
function [matQ, matR] = HS(A)

[m,n]=size(A);
Q = eye(n);

%Loop
for (k = 1:n)

    x=A(k:m, k);


    I = eye(m-k+1);
    e1 = I(:,1);

    if( (sign(x(1)) == 0) )
        sinal = 1;
    else
        sinal = sign(x(1));
    end


    v = x + sign(x(1))*norm(x)*e1;

    Hk = eye(m-k+1) - 2/(v' * v) * (v * v');

    Qk = [eye(k-1) , zeros(k-1, m-k+1); zeros(m-k+1, k-1), Hk];

    A = Qk*A;

    Q = Q*Qk;
endfor
matQ = Q
matR = A
endfunction
```

But when I call it in octave, I get the following message: 'HS' undefined near line 5, column 1

I have no idea what am I doing wrong, since I've made other functions that works well.  I also know that the algorithm works well because I have tested it before.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the function saved in the current working directory?

Comment: Yes. I tested another function at the same directory and it worked well

Comment: Are you running the function from the command line or from another function?

Comment: Running from command line